# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, trying to assign an array to a int

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I'm appending to a queue an array, and then I pop it from the queue and assign it to another value.

```
u = [1, [2,3]]
```

After I retrieve it, I do `u[1]` to iterate through the numbers that are listed inside that index.

This is the idea. In my code it doesn't work tho. At the for loop I get this warning `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

```
Q.append(s)
while len(Q) != 0:
    u = Q.pop()
    for v in u[1]:
        // Do something
```

I know that u is an int and because of that I cannot call it by u[1], so how am I supposed to turn around this problem?

Comment: are you tried to iterate over an int in this line? `for v in u[1]:`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You don't do that.  What's  in `Q`?

Comment: you DONT want to do that

Comment: my bad, I though that this is a list of numbers, and didn't understand that it's a nested list there.

Comment: There's not enough context here to suggest a specific solution, but having a list that contains a mix of ints and lists is a **strong** clue that very poor decisions have been made elsewhere in this code.

Comment: I did that kind of list because I am working on a bfs and that list contains the nodes of the graph and for each node, there is a list of the adj nodes.

Answer (score 0):

the root problem is that your queue contains data of different types - some you can subscript (i.e. your list [2,3]), as well as the int type '1'.

If you must deal with mixed types, you might have to check the type of each item you are popping off the queue, for example:

```
q = []

q.append(1)
q.append([2,3])

while len(q) != 0:
    u = q.pop()
    if type(u) is int:
            print("item is an int:", u)
    elif type(u) is list:
        print("item is a list")
        for v in u:
            print("  list contains:", v)
```

Alternatively, ensure that all items on the queue are lists, if that is what you actually need:

```
q = []

q.append([1]) # note
q.append([2,3])

while len(q) != 0:
    u = q.pop()
    for v in u:
        print("list contains:", v)
```

Comment: It worked after I put the for loop inside the `if type(u) is list` condition.